# No physical template file was found for template Home

Tags: templates, umbraco, startup

This is the error when starting Umbraco:
[Browser error upon startup-click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtYXE.jpg)

The template for the Home page exists ([project path]\Views\USNStandardPage.cshtml. ***I don't know how to find what template the code is calling for.***

The appSettings tag in web.config has:

`<add key="owin:appStartup" value="UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup" />`

When searching the contents of the project files, I find no reference to the UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup value which I presume is the next place to look.

In the App_Start folder there is the following code but the breakpoint doesn't get hit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ESCProject11
{
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
  }
}
```

The site uses a uSkinned theme.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you are adding your template? directly from Visual Studio or by CMS interface?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you're looking a the owin stuff in the web.config. The error that you have there is one that you will get when you have no template assigned to the node.

In your Umbraco back office, have a look at the home node, and on the "Properties" tab, is there a template assigned in the dropdown? If not, you will need to assign one (choose it from the dropdown) and save and publish the page. If ione is assigned, it will also tell you which template it is looking for, you can look for the selected template in the Settings section, under "templates" in Umbraco.

The route mapping stuff that you have there won't get hit, as Umbraco does it's own route mapping, you'd have to call the route registration as part of an Umbraco startup handler. For more information on this, check out the Umbraco docs here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/Routing/custom-routes

Comment: ...and even in the CMS if Home template is already assigned to the home node, it doesn't hurt to check in your IDE (i.e. Visual Studio), that you have all master templates included in your project before you publish the site out.

Comment: Saved me lots of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that template doesn't get created out of the box.

Been working with Umbraco 7.4.3 and it appears during install wizard when you select first starter kit it installs blog, pages, etc. but not adding master layouts.

Go to Developer > expand "Packages" > Install Starter Kit > Select appropriate template to install and then it run ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error occurred on an Controller.Action marked as privet changing the action's accessor to public solved the issue.